# Not able to install Windows 10 on an existing Ubuntu OS on an HP laptop

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot

I am trying to install Windows 10 on an HP laptop which is currently running Ubuntu 18.04. I go to the **boot device options** it gives me the option of booting from a USB Flash Drive but when I select it, it doesn't start off windows installation, but instead, it boots Ubuntu 18.04 without displaying any options. I tried resetting the BIOS but that didn't work either. The only way left now that I can think of is to take out the hard drive out of the laptop and format it. Still, I thought if someone could help me out with this issue it would be great. Please do note that I don't have any data that needs to be preserved so feel free to suggest any formatting options that don't require me to take out the HDD out of the laptop

Answer (score 0):

Most BIOSes on current computers detect USB pendrives as disks, and not as USB removable media, so even if you put USB drives first in the boot priority, your USB drive is still behind the boot drive. Check if your usb is listed under disk boot order, and put it first on that list in that case.